# Smooth rotation with second

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I was wondering if there is any way to make a smoother rotation of the circle?

This is what I have so far:

```
  let angle = 0;
  let pointCount = 12;
  let speed;
  strokeWeight(60);

  rotate(second());
  for(let i = angle; i < radians(360 + angle) ; i += radians(360 / pointCount)){
    let x = width / 2 * Math.cos(i);
    let y = width / 2 * Math.sin(i);
    point(x, y)
  }
```

The rotation jumps every second, but I would like it to move smoothly.

I used rotate because I think it would be the most simple way, but if it's inconvenient please let me know if I should try something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`millis()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/millis) function:

> Returns the number of milliseconds (thousandths of a second) since starting the sketch [...]

The default unit of the [`rotate()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/rotate) angel is radians. If you want a complete ture every second, you have to scale the number of milliseconds by `2*PI / 1000`:

```js
rotate(millis() * 2*PI / 1000);
```

Comment: Ah I see, thank you!